# Xcode SDK & Trackpad gestures: animations setup

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion, xcode4.3

**Q** The question is, is there a way to disable the animations happening with the trackpad-gestures at the currently public-available Xcode 4.3.2 running MacOS 10.7.3 ?

**Description** I'm very concerned with the new Lion animations while going forward/back with a trackpad gestures. With a keyboard shortcuts the page changes *instantly* and with a gesture it takes about a second or two spraying around my concentration on the things that need to be found in the code.

**Tried** What i tried is to read the defaults in the Terminal looking for any animation/duration keys - without success.

**Notes** Looks like mr. Cook [criticizes](http://www.electronista.com/articles/12/04/24/apple.ceo.slams.windows.8.ultrabook.idea/) the things Apple is doing itself while preparing the combined mobile/stationary look&feel. If there's any startup project that collects all the user's customizing, i'll be glad to know. So far i tried the `itweax` application, it doesn't have yet the expected features however.

Safari stuff is not as much about the content importance, so i would not mind to leave the Safari animations, but changing it on the system level for all the apps is also good.

**PS** I believe that *is* about the “software tools commonly used by programmers” mentioned at “What kind of questions can I ask here?” [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) section.

Comment: Do you want to disable the gestures, or disable the animation transition that happens after the gesture - so you still want to move forward / back but _instantly_?

Comment: @jrturton I'd like exactly to keep the gestures and get rid of fancy-wow animations, particularly at the Xcode files navigation, it would be also nice to be able to configure Safari in the same way, however that is much lower priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about disabling animations but if you want to trigger app keyboard commands through gestures, I found [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?p=2817) helpful with some of the major Lion annoyances. Ex. I was able to configure FireFox to do Home/End on a 3-finger swipe up/down.

Comment: It's working, very impressive app (it might also help me with Eclipse), will need to get a closer look on how it works and how much resources it needs.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to disable the animation.

You can, however, disable the page swiping functionality:

```
System Preferences > Trackpad > More Gestures > Deselect "Swipe between pages"
```

Unfortunately, there is no setting to disable or change the speed of the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, as you seem to be familiar with the problem, maybe there's any way to bind the gesture to the keys combination for the particular app ? I mean with the hotkey there's no animation and i could use some helping software if that's available. Disabling is not a perfect option as i like this gesture function very much.